# How to load image from a clone git repo on Colab?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I have clone a repo on Colab and would like to load an image. Anyone any idea what is the simplest way to do it?

I want to load an image called heatmap.png to my Colab notebook.

thanks for any help.

[image]

Comment: Any plot image library helps, for example https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html, or https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-imshow-method/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example notebook that shows how to display an image in the browser read from a local file on the Colab backend:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jWHKR6rhhyZtUulttBD6Pxd_AJhgtVaV

The key bit:

```
from IPython.display import Image
Image('220px-TensorFlowLogo.svg.png')
```

In your case, the file path would be the full `/content/...` path.